# How can I fix this error coming from eslint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there a better way to write this part of the code? It works, but the eslint is complaining that

*'resp' is already declared in the upper scope*

In this part

```
    return parseJSON(resp).then((resp) => {
      throw resp
    })
```

This is the entire code

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const parseJSON = (resp) => (resp.json ? resp.json() : resp)

    const checkStatus = (resp) => {
      if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
        return resp
      }
      return parseJSON(resp).then((resp) => {
        throw resp
      })
    }
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    try {
      const data = await fetch('http://myurl/api', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
      }).then(checkStatus)
        .then(parseJSON)
      this.setState({ data })
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error })
    }
  }
```

Comment: This `.then((resp)` is the issue. You have same named variable in parent arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

You have variable name `resp` in twice in the same scope on below lines:

`const checkStatus = (resp) => {`

and `return parseJSON(resp).then((resp) => {`.

change one of resp.